# Kafka stream application stopped with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have installed Kafka 1.0.0 with help of docker composer and I am running this Kafka successfully with two brokers. I created a topic manually with partition and inserted the events.

Now I am running a application with 1.0.0 Kafka Stream by pointing to this Kafka. After running my application for some time, Following messages were showing in log and stopped from run. Except producer request.timeout.ms, all other config parameters are default parameters and producer request.timeout.ms is 120seconds.

Before stopping with below messages, Couple of times I observed `'Trying to rejoin the consumer group now. org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException:' and  'Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException:'` messages in the log.

What would be the possible reason? Please help me.

Messages before stopping:

```
2017-12-07 06:17:03,122 WARN o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender [kafka-producer-network-thread | sample-app-0.0.1-7f99fa3f-4487-48dc-af3f-9296ee513452-StreamThread-1-producer] [Producer clientId=sample-app-0.0.1-7f99fa3f-4487-48dc-af3f-9296ee513452-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with sample id 14099 on topic-partition abc-0, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION
2017-12-07 06:18:02,675 ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl [kafka-producer-network-thread | sample-app-0.0.1-7f99fa3f-4487-48dc-af3f-9296ee513452-StreamThread-1-producer] task [2_0] Error sending record (key 5a12c9ade532af0412fc7bcc.5a12c9ade532af0412fc7bca value com.sample.kafka.streams.SampleEvent@4a56c681 timestamp 1512363589768) to topic abc due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 9 record(s) for abc-0: 189836 ms has passed since last append; No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task.
2017-12-07 06:18:02,927 INFO o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [sample-app-0.0.1-7f99fa3f-4487-48dc-af3f-9296ee513452-StreamThread-1] [Consumer clientId=sample-app-0.0.1-7f99fa3f-4487-48dc-af3f-9296ee513452-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=sample-app-0.0.1] Discovered coordinator 1.1.1.1:32775 (id: 2147482645 rack: null)
```

Comment: Seem you have some network issues: NETWORK_EXCEPTION -- try to increase producer config `retries` and/or `retry.backoff.ms`.

Comment: unable to solved by increasing retries and retry backoff ms.

Comment: I tried with another two different single broker kafka clusters. I got only `ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl [kafka-producer-network-thread | sample-app-0.0.1-ebe-StreamThread-1-producer] task [2_0] Error sending record (key 5a12c15b value com.sample.kafka.streams.SampleEvent@4829054e timestamp 1512659275284) to topic abc due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 14 record(s) for abc-0: 34328 ms has passed since last append; No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task.` exception.But not got the `NETWORK_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: This might relate to a know bug in the producer. You can try to increase `request.timeout.ms` to guard against it.